# SQL - Column parsing

Tags: sql, parsing

This question is related to separating data from one column and putting it into multiple other columns.

I have a column that hold record data like;

original table called - `character_Collection`

```
Columns id,text
id=1 text = ('10596=MAD 10999=THE 11555=HATTER 16666= ')
```

Yes there is always a space after the equals if there is no Data.

I think I need to use the case commands to move the data to the column.

Oracle DB

Please can someone advise, I would like to make the columns look like;

```
id first second third fourth 
1   THE   MAD   HATTER null
```

Comment: You would really be much better off using a regular programming language-- this would be difficult in SQL.

Comment: What's the database? The solution is very database-specific.

Comment: this is an Oracle DB

Comment: how did you decide which went into first, second and third?

Comment: are there always exactly 4 items in the list?

Comment: No there could be 8-10 but I will always want the same specfic numbers for 
first second third fourth

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x strongly suggests you need a procedural language to split a string in pure SQL, but that Microsoft SQL 2016 (not Oracle) has such a feature built-in. I don't think you can do what you want in pure standard SQL.